# What is the best way to get elements attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm like most of novice web developers in most cases use jQuery, but more often I started to use  clean js. So from here is my question: is it god practice to use clean js in jQuery scope, for example if i need to get elements class i can do this like:

```
jQuery('div#grid a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.getAttribute('class'));
    console.log(this.className);
    console.log(jQuery(this).attr('class'));
});
```

But what is the best way?

Comment: Define 'best'. Performance-wise, accessing `className` attribute directly is optimal (no function invoked, no object created).

Comment: …and in this case, it's even optimal in code length and readability. Of course it implies that your fellow devs need to know what `className` is, the jQuery-only expression is more descriptive for those who don't.

Comment: Exactly. Still I wonder, will `Element.className` win against `Element.getAttribute('class')` in every existing implementation. )

Comment: @raina77ow as getAttribute() is a function and className  is a property, it should always be better to use className

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's better to use the `this.className` because it is the fastest among the three. Here's a demo which you can run and see the speed of execution: [jquery attr(class) vs js.className](http://jsperf.com/jquery-attr-class-vs-js-classname/2)

You can see after running the test that `className` property is the fastest one.

Answer (score 3):

Yes,use clean js in jQuery scope is good practise.Because this is native work with DOM and it works more faster.

[Perfomance Test](http://jsperf.com/browser-diet-this-attr-id-vs-this-id)

Answer (score 2):

There is always a performance improvement using native script rather than making a jQuery function call to do the same thing.

This gain however can be imperceptible for small numbers of elements. Thus the trade off becomes simpler, more readable code vs gains that may not make much impact on the UI